# Windows Search using cortana closes 2 seconds after typing a single character and no result are displayed

Tags: cortana

I can type one letter in the search field and then am prevented from typing more. Then cortana closes:

[image]

I tried running the windows index troubleshooter, and no problems were found.
I tried running sfc /scannow. 
I tried deleting this key described by [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/947392/windows-10-search-cant-find-any-applications-even-calculator) which didn't work:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion‌​\Explorer\FolderType‌​s\{ef87b4cb-f2ce-478‌​5-8658-4ca6c63e38c6}‌​\TopViews\{00000000-‌​0000-0000-0000-00000‌​0000000}
```

After creating a new account, cortana works but I want to keep the original account.

While trying to follow [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1140716/windows-10-anniversary-update-search-bar-doesnt-work-after-update):
When I stop the service named WSearch, briefly I can use cortana again but the service restarts itself after about ten seconds so I can't run the command marked at code segment 3 below suggested by the post to do while the service is closed and I don't know how to disable it. I'm running Windows 10 home and GPedit.msc is not available. 
[image]
Ignoring disabling WSearch and running the similar commands to reinstall windows store suggested above and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/cant-type-in-windows-10-search-bar/7dce8411-8671-4d3e-90d1-b9bdc0aa4734) produce errors saying a higher version of the package is already installed.
1:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

2:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

3:

```
$manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest
```

Comment: You say your problem is restricted to your user account. But everything you have tried so far is machine-global. You shouldn't have.

Comment: What is the question then? How to fix the issue or how to disable Cortana (or either)?

Comment: @Dave My question is how to fix the search functionality in the start menu with or without "Cortana".The user at the question linked above and below said Tweaking.com's repair tool worked but he hasn't come back to answer what function of the tool fixed it. https://superuser.com/questions/1140716/windows-10-anniversary-update-search-bar-doesnt-work-after-update

Answer (score 1):

For me the following post solved the problem:

make a backup of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search` in the registry and then delete the whole entry.

(found here: https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/83709-start-menu-crashing-after-typing-few-letters.html#post1561835)

Comment: If you are quoting somebody, please identify the original author by name and link to the post.  And it would be great to link to an authoritative reference, like microsoft.com. … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Of the many potential fixes this issue has had mentioned online, this is the one that worked for me - no restart or log-off required!

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade released or made available to me today (Windows 10 home creators edition) version 1703 build 15073.138 fixed the problem for me. Whether it was a corrupted file (likely since the other user account worked) or a bug, maybe will never known.