# Windows-10 update KB4058043: Search bar doesn't work after update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

After the most recent Store reliability update (KB4058043), I have the exact same problems as described in a year-old update issue:

*[Windows 10 Anniversary update: Search bar doesn't work after update](https://superuser.com/questions/1140716/windows-10-anniversary-update-search-bar-doesnt-work-after-update)*

In addition to the start menu, entering search text in the "Windows Settings" dialog's search-box also freezes it.

I've tried all solutions provided therein, but none has worked so far. So far I've tried solutions based on

- DCIM tool
- A PowerShell script
- Tweaking.com's repair tool

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the update in question?

Comment: Windows 10 (esp Home) has the habit of automatically applying updates. I dont think there is a way to avoid that update.

Comment: this update only replaces a DLL related to the store service, so I doubt that the update causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) – Process. Please try to manually disable Windows Explorer and re-start it to check the result.

Besides, restart the system in Safe Mode, or with network enabled to check the result.

Besides, it is recommended to uninstall the specific update (KB4058043), restart the system and confirm that if the problem happens again, it would helpful to identify whether it is this update related question.